# Mixing *vargs and **kargs arguments in function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def func(*v, **k): pass
func(**{'a': 1}, *(1, 2, 3))     # ERROR...
func(a=1, *(1, 2, 3))            # OK...
```

I don't get why this first doesn't work, instead the second does.

Someone could just tell "because the implementation says so", but I would like also to know *why* the implementation  says so. Couldn't the implementation translate the first to the second in order to make this call work?

Comment: The second only works if `a`, is the 4th defined parameter.

Comment: You can do `func(*(1, 2, 3), **{'a': 1})`.  The grammar simply specifies that `*args` goes before `**kwargs`.  Why?  Because it doesn't matter, so they simply chose one order.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Mmmmh....Isn't there behind this solution a performance reason?

Comment: @antox: I don't think so.  The parser would be affected only marginally, and at run time there wouldn't be any performance difference at all.  I think it's more about consistency -- the order doesn't really matter, so choose one and enforce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, the second line works only if the `a` parameter is the last (the forth). for example, the following code will not work:

```
def func(a,b,c,d):
    pass

func(a=1, *(1, 2, 3))
```

And to you question, I think the problem with the first line:

```
func(**{'a': 1}, *(1, 2, 3))
```

is that you can have multiple values for the same parameter this way, if the dictionary contains one of the first 3 parameters.

the difference is that the dictionary can be a variable and have different value on different runs so this code always considered illegal

Comment: `func(*(1, 2, 3), **{'a': 1}` is allowed, so the reasoning probably wasn't what you guessed.

Comment: interesting, Thanks. so maybe because it will not be clear that `a` is the last variable if you put it in the beginning. or maybe just because parameters order is important , just like everytime you call a function and *vargs should be before **kargs (edit: now I saw you already wrote it in a comment..)

Answer (score 1):

Passing positional arugments and keyword arguments like this is part of the language's syntax, not a run-time feature. That is, `*(1,2,3)` does not simply create a special object that is passed to the function when it is called and "somehow" used to assign values to the defined parameters. As such, allowing this kind of flexibility in the ordering would come at the cost of greatly complicating the parser for no real benefit.